# sql inner join query

Tags: php, mysql

This is myquery in these query i have fetch the result from 4 tables using inner join.It return all the records which are matched from 4 tables.
But i want to also get that reords which are matched in fl_customer_profile table and fl_users table.And also get that records which ids are matched in 4 tables.

```
SELECT u.*,c.*,s.*,p.*
FROM fl_users u
INNER JOIN fl_customer_profile c
    on u.id = c.userID
INNER JOIN fl_customer_subscription s
    on u.id = s.userid
INNER JOIN fl_subscription p
    on s.planId = p.id
```

fl_users Table

```
ID
| 879 | 

| 884  |
```

fl_customer_profile Table

```
userID
| 879 | 

| 884  |
```

Comment: Please paste the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your are trying to get all the records that matches fl_customer_profile  and fl_users whether they are present in other tables or not, Inner join will return records if they are present in both tables , while left join will return all records from left table and from second table will return only matched rows

```
SELECT u.*,c.*,s.*,p.*
FROM fl_users u
INNER JOIN fl_customer_profile c
    on u.id = c.userID
LEFT JOIN fl_customer_subscription s
    on u.id = s.userid
LEFT JOIN fl_subscription p
    on s.planId = p.id
```

Comment: Thanks for these solution